# spring tiles vs jsp include

Tags: spring, jsp, spring-mvc

I was working earlier in jsp/servlet but recently moved to spring mvc project.In this project we are using tiles

```
<div id="content">
   <tiles:insertAttribute name="content" />
</div>
```

I know why jsp include is used(used for including one page inside another) and I am thinking tiles are also used for the same purpose(Please clarify if I am wrong).

If both does the same purpose then why tiles why not jsp include.

In this link only theoretical points are covered but I need some examples proving the arguments.

1. Code Repetition is reduced  Use of Tiles reduce the code repetition to a great extent. Code repetition is bad but repetition
   of  layout logic could be worst. Tiles also handle this issue. As
   you have layout templates based on  which all the pages are
   combined, you don't need to repeat the code for layout. Other view 
   components are also reusable and can be used in the same application
   at other places reducing the code repetition.
2. Low coupling between pages  Coupling is the degree of interactivity
   between two entities. It is always suggested to minimize  coupling
   between unrelated classes, packages, and so on. Same principle is
   applied to view  components. Tiles reduce the coupling between
   unrelated view components.
3. High layout control  Tiles provide great layout control by providing
   layout templates.
4. I18N support for locale-specific loading
5. Dynamic Page building 
   Pages are built dynamically in tiles. You can control the page view by configuring it through 
   xml.
6. Elimination of duplicate and redundant information 
   Tiles eliminate the duplicate and redundant information in the configuration file by providing 
   Tiles inheritance.
7. Central location for view components 
   Tiles save definition of all the components at one place (in tilesDef.xml) and hence can be 
   modified easily when required.*

Can anybody please help me

Comment: The differences you highlighted may sound theoretical but are more than that. Is there any specific attributes you are looking for?

Comment: @Atul The differences are taken from the link provided.I need some proof supporting those